# Create an Observable by combining other Observables by sampling from first when in second is emiting event

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I need to get combining of two observers when one is an infinite data source, and another is an indicator for getting last value from first.
I will draw an image here what I want:
[image]

I have looked on http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html#combining but none has fit my requirements.

Comment: Have you tried zip? http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html `Observable.zip(firstObservable, secondObservable, (first, second) -> first)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved quite easily with `flatMap`:

```
observable2
    .flatMap(value -> observable1.take(1))
```

Comment: After some time I start using this option of controling events, but in a bit changed form: `observable2.flatMap(value -> observable1.startWith(defaultIfEmpty).takeLast(1))`

Answer (score 4):

`public final  Observable sample(Observable sampler)`
http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#sample(rx.Observable)

Comment: All the answers are correct. I even surprised in that huge amount of solutions. This one is really simplest.

Comment: @msangel They're not quite the same. The `sample` operator will, for example, treat the completed event on the sampling observable (observable2 in your example) as a sampling event.
Also you won't get duplicates. Say for example your sampled observable emits an item A and a short time afterwards your sampling observable emitsitems  B and C then you will only get a single item
A emitted by the downstream observable.

Comment: This will not fire if  `observable1` hasn't change. But I need a value of   `observable1` anytime  `observable2` have changed, even if same value. I know this requirement was not mentioned in the question, so I am writing this right now. I also believe that the comment above is also about this.

Answer (score 2):

Try `withLatestFrom` (it's marked experimental but it has been in the RxJava API for a while now)

```
Observable<Long> interval = Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<Long> slowerInterval = Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
slowerInterval.withLatestFrom(interval, new Func2<Long, Long, Long>() {
     @Override
            public Long call(Long first, Long second) {
                return second;
            }
})
```

Comment: This is definitely the more elegant way, nice :)

Comment: It won't work exactly as required - for given example it will produce something like: 60, 80, 100, 100. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: 'withLatestFrom' only emits when the source observable emits. You can check at [rxmarbles](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom).

Answer (score 1):

I created a small example with `interval` operators.

```
Observable<Long> interval = Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
Observable<Long> slowerInterval = Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
Observable.combineLatest(
            interval,
            slowerInterval,
            new Func2<Long, Long, Long>() {

                Long previousSecond = null;

                @Override
                public Long call(Long first, Long second) {
                    if (!second.equals(previousSecond)) {
                        previousSecond = second;
                        return first;
                    } else {
                        return null;
                    }
                }
            })
            .filter(value -> value != null)
            .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(Long value) {
                    // Value gets emitted here every time slowerInterval emits
                }

                ...
            });
```

**Explanation:** Because of the way `combineLatest` works, I needed to cache the second observables value and check if it has changed before emitting a value from first observable downstream. If it hasn't changed I emit `null`, which is then filtered out. There probably is a more elegant way to do this, but I couldn't think of one.

Comment: I guess someone downvote this because of filtering null, which might be a valid event value, but this can be solved by wrapping actual value in holder (or optional), and then unwrapping. But this answer is still quite useful - it show the most flexibility in creating of combined observable. Thanks.